# Prove that a function is surjective and injective with symmetric difference

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have this function:

$D=\{17,18,19,20,21\}$
$$f:P(N) \to P(N), f(B) = B\triangle D$$

I'd like to prove whether this function is surjective or/and injective.

I'm kinda lost of what I need to assume or how to prove this, some hints maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic facts about symmetric difference: for all $x,y,z$, 
$$(x\Delta y) \Delta z = x\Delta (y \Delta z).$$
(Prove this if it's not among the things you can assume or have already proved.) Thus 
$$(x\Delta y) \Delta y = x\Delta (y \Delta y) = x\Delta \emptyset = x.
$$
Hence $f$ has an inverse, $f^{-1} = f$, and therefore (why?) $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Impressive amount of answers (and score) in just 46 days, keep the good work :)

Comment: @Mirko Thank you. (& welcome to NYC)

Answer (score 0):

The function is injective iff $f(X_1)=f(X_2)$ implies that $X_1=X_2$, for all sets $X_1$, $X_2\in\mathcal{P}(N)$. So, it amounts to show that if $X_1\Delta D=X_2\Delta D$, then $X_1=X_2$.

As of surjectivity, we need to show that if $Y\in \mathcal{P}(N)$, then there exists $X\in \mathcal{P}(N)$ such that $Y=f(X)$, i.e., that $Y=X\Delta D$. Taking $X=Y\Delta D$ works. This is because, as pointed out above, $D\Delta D=\emptyset$, so we can "solve for $X$".